# .NET internal Encoding

Tags: .net, string, encoding, character-encoding

what is the internal encoding from .NET applications?(for example string objects) Can I define what encoding my appliction should use? If i write a .net string to a file. What encoding has the string?

**//edit**

```
Dim test as String="Das ist ein Test" <---what Encoding has this String?

Dim reader as New IO.StreamReader(docPath, _
    System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("shift-jis"))

test=reader.ReadToEnd() <---and now? What Encoding has this String?
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Dim test as String="Das ist ein Test" <---what Encoding has this String?
```

UTF-16

```
Dim reader as New IO.StreamReader(docPath,
    System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("shift-jis"))
test=reader.ReadToEnd <---and now? What Encoding has this String?
```

Still UTF-16. The `StreamReader` class looks at the bytes in `docPath` and converts them to UTF-16 based on the shift-jis encoding.

Comment: +1 for direct look at the OP's code and for the information about StreamReader.

Answer (score 3):

`System.String` is UTF-16. You can convert that to various other encodings using derivatives of the [`System.Text.Encoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx) class.

In response to edit:
`System.IO.StreamReader`, as far as I am aware tries to "guess" as to the correct encoding if one is not specified. `System.IO.StreamWriter` writes as UTF-8, IIRC. I'm less familiar with these classes so take that information at your own risk ;)

Answer (score 2):

As all of the other answers: yes, 2 byte Unicode (UTF-16). And yes, you can control how it writes to disc, like described by @Billy ONeal.

Concerning your question whether it is possible to control this: No, this is not possible. .NET will always run on Unicode UTF-16 internally. There are no settings for this.

Answer (score 1):

Internally .NET uses **Unicode**  --**UPDATED**-- UTF-16.

However, if you write the string to a file, you have to provide an encoding. If you don't .NET will choose an encoding for you - this is usually **UTF8**.
Here is reflectored File.WriteAllText:

```
public static void WriteAllText(string path, string contents)
{
    if (path == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("path");
    }
    if (path.Length == 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(Environment.GetResourceString("Argument_EmptyPath"));
    }
    InternalWriteAllText(path, contents, StreamWriter.UTF8NoBOM);
}
```

Comment: Actually, it's 2 bytes per code point, not per character. Things like accent marks can be separate code points but be printed as part of the same character. Also, it uses UTF-16, which means a code point can *potentially* be 4 bytes, though nobody uses anything outside the basic multilingual plane in practice.

Comment: Actually, it is 2 bytes per code unit, not code point :-) Code points above U+FFFF require 2 code units in UTF-16 (and .NET user UTF-16).