# Can't locate the difference between my C# encryption function, and my PHP encryption function

Tags: c#, php, encryption

I wrote (what I thought to be) identical encryption functions in PHP and C#. However, encrypting the same string is not producing identical results. I'm no expert in either C# nor PHP so I was hoping someone might be able to spot the difference that for some reason I am not catching here.

**PHP function:**

```
function encrypt($string, $key) { 
$result = NULL; 
for($i=0; $i<strlen($string); $i++) { 
$char = substr($string, $i, 1); 
$keychar = substr($key, ($i % strlen($key))-1, 1); 
$char = chr(ord($char)+ord($keychar)); 
$result.=$char; 
}

//return $result;
return $result;
}
```

**C# function:**

```
        public static string encrypt_php_data(string stringToEncrypt, string key)
        {
            var result = string.Empty;

            for (int i = 0; i < stringToEncrypt.Length; i++)
            {
                string keychar = phpSubStr_replacement(key, (i % key.Length) - 1);
                result += (char)(Convert.ToChar(stringToEncrypt.Substring(i, 1)) + Convert.ToChar(keychar));
            }

            return result;
        }

private static string phpSubStr_replacement(string stringToGrab, int startIndex)
        {

            if (startIndex < 0)
            {
                // Take from end of string
                return stringToGrab.Substring(stringToGrab.Length + startIndex, 1);
            }

            else
            {
                // Take from beginning of string
                return stringToGrab.Substring(startIndex, 1);
            }
        }
```

Here are the results of  encrypting identical strings:

String encrypted: 09/16/2011 15:27:45

password used: somekey

```
C# Result: ©¬©¤  «ª©¡ 

PHP Result: ©¬žž›š—©¤ – Ÿ«ª©¡š
```

#### Note:

Not all outputs vary from each other. I cannot understand why some are different, while others produce the same outcome, makes no sense.

I look forward to your responses,

Evan

Comment: are these on the same system?  The PHP version looks like the C# version but with extra characters.

Comment: Have you looked at the encoding of the strings?

Comment: Could you explain a bit further? I have not ...

Comment: @Chris Yes these are on the same system.

Comment: What do you want to use this encryption for? It has a number of weaknesses. It's basically a stream cypher, and thus has the associated problems. In particular it's broken if you ever reuse a key or if your input exceeds the key length.

Comment: @CodeInChaod I'm using this encryption to encrypt values within a URL. The user cannot know the values being passed for security reasons.

Comment: Why the hell do you use homebrew encryption for anything security relevant? There are dozens of secure algorithms made by experts. Your encryption is at a technical level of hundreds of years ago.

Comment: @CodeInChaos all of the encryption algorithms I found required a module of some sort - which my hosting does not support.

Answer (score 2):

First, you really should be using a cryptographically-strong encryption function because schemes like this one where individual bytes are summed with key bytes can be easily broken. That being said, the main reason why the two codes differ in output is that PHP is performing the addition operations on 8-bit ASCII-encoded bytes whereas C# is performing the addition operations on 16-bit UTF-16 code units (See: [.NET internal Encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4155130/196844)).

The "fix" on the C# side is to convert the string-to-be-encrypted and the key to their ASCII encodings before performing the addition operations:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Test
{
    public class SO7449615
    {
        public static string encrypt_php_data(string stringToEncrypt, string key) {
            ASCIIEncoding asciiEncoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] stringToEncryptBytes = asciiEncoding.GetBytes(stringToEncrypt);
            byte[] keyBytes = asciiEncoding.GetBytes(key);

            byte[] retBytes = new byte[stringToEncryptBytes.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < stringToEncryptBytes.Length; ++i) {
                byte keyByte = keyBytes[(i + keyBytes.Length - 1) % keyBytes.Length];
                retBytes[i] = (byte)(stringToEncryptBytes[i] + keyByte);
                //Console.Write(' ');
                //Console.Write(retBytes[i]);
            }
            //Console.WriteLine();
            return asciiEncoding.GetString(retBytes);
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string stringToEncrypt = "test";
            string key = "somekey";
            Console.WriteLine(encrypt_php_data(stringToEncrypt, key));
        }
    }
}
```

It is equivalent to your original PHP code as well as the following version:

```
<?php
function encrypt($string, $key) {
    $string_len = strlen($string);
    $key_len = strlen($key);
    $ret = "";

    for ($i = 0; $i < $string_len; ++$i) {
        $key_char = $key[($i + $key_len - 1) % $key_len];
        $b = ord($string[$i]) + ord($key_char);
        $ret .= chr($b);
        //echo " $b";
    }
    //echo "\n";
    return $ret;
}

echo encrypt("test", "somekey") . "\n";
```

But again, I do not recommend that these functions be used to encrypt data. This `encrypt()` function employs a weak encryption scheme that is easily broken. Also, it does not allow non-ASCII strings to be encrypted or used as keys.

You mentioned that you are running PHP on a web host that does not allow extensions. Have you specifically checked for the presence of the [mcrypt extension](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php)? Perhaps your web host has it pre-installed.

Comment: Yes I have done a check for this extension, it does not exist. I may just upgrade to a new host.

Comment: @Evan: Out of curiosity, which web hosting company are you using?

Comment: @Evan: If encrypting strings is a critical aspect of your app, then it might be a good idea to switch hosting companies. If not, you can simply use a pure PHP implementation of the RSA algorithm (e.g. http://stevish.com/rsa-encryption-in-pure-php).

Comment: I was using free hosting for the time being (Zymos), but I will be changing hosts after this debacle.

Comment: RC4 is a lot more secure than what you are using and is extremely easy to program.  It is obsolescent for really secure work, but fine for mid-level security.

Answer (score 0):

Write output in hexadecimal, there are a lot of characters which is unseen

Comment: I understand that characters are missing. Regardless, though, the outputs are not identical.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect C# adds the key modulo 2^16 (It's using 16 bit chars) and php modulo 2^8 using 8 bit chars.

Also your C# code is very bloated. I'd try something like the following:

```
public static string encrypt_php_data(string stringToEncrypt, string key)
{
    var result = string.Empty;
    for (int i = 0; i < stringToEncrypt.Length; i++)
    {
        char keychar = key[(i+key.Length- 1) % key.Length];
        result += (char)((stringToEncrypt[i] + keychar));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: How would I go about fixing this then? Is there some way I could specify which to use?

Comment: What encoding do you want? And what do you want to happen if you get a character as input that can't be represented in the reduced charset? Unicode has been introduced for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

Your "encryption" function is subject to overflow.  When you add two ASCII values like you do with `ord($char) + ord($keychar)` in the PHP version, you can easily end up with a value that is no longer a valid ASCII character.  PHP and C# may handle this differently, and that's what you're seeing.  It works fine for some characters like the numerals, but gets messed up for characters like the '\' and ':'.

You should really use an established encryption or encoding function here, but if you really need to roll your own, you may need to redesign it as this one is broken.

Comment: Unfortunately, my hosting does not support any PHP modules - making it necessary for me to produce my own. Might you have any tips for me?

Comment: Here, overflow is not an issue because PHP's `chr()` function mods the argument by 256: http://codepad.org/adOqAg5e

Comment: I see, so in C# where an overflow exception would be thrown, PHP self-fixes it?